# Possible mathematical finishes to the darts game 501

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I was recently posed a question by a friend -

> How many possible finishes exist within the darts game 501 which include 3 (or more doubles) and using no more than 9 darts?

For those unfamiliar with 501 the premise is as follows.

- Each player has unlimited darts which are thrown in a set of three.
- Each player begins with the score 501
- The aim is to reduce the score to zero in as few darts as possible

> The ultimate aim of each player is to achieve a **9 dart finish**.  A nine-dart finish is a perfect leg, using only nine darts, the fewest possible, to checkout from 501. It is notoriously difficult to achieve, even by the game's top professionals. It is considered to be the highest single-game achievement in the sport, similar to a maximum 147 break in snooker or a 300-point game in bowling.

## Example Answer

My answer was the following

> - Darts 1,2,3 each hit *Treble 20*  (180 score leaving 321 remaining)
> - Darts 4,5,6 each hit *Bullseye* (double) 150 score leaving 171))
> - Darts 7,8,9 each hit *Treble 19* leaving zero

**How many further methods exist of scoring 501 with 9 darts and using three doubles in order to do so?**

## Edit to add Fundamentals of Scoring in Darts

A dartboard is divided evenly into 20 segments comprising the full 360 degrees of the board.  The segments are numbered 1 to 20 representing the score for hitting each segment with a dart.  Within the segments designated bands allow the score to be doubled or trebled.

Therefore the maximum score with a single dart is 60, achieved by hitting the treble 20.  The lowest score is 0 (a miss) or 1 for hitting the 1 segment.  In addition two centre circles exist worth 25 and 50 points respectively.  The 50 point ring is classed as a double and is known generally as the bullseye.

With any single dart, barring a miss, a player has the chance to hit one of 62 point scoring zones, however the maximum score per dart cannot exceed 60.

[image: A dartboard with scoring]

Comment: The question appears to be incomplete without a specification of what the possible scores from one dart are. Also, does the goal of 501 have to be reached exactly, or can it be overshot? And does the order of scores within each set of 3 count?

Comment: Strictly speaking, according to official rules, you have to finish with a double when playing $501$. Are you completely certain that this is not the case here?

Comment: You are correct but for the purposes of the question finishing with a double is not required.  Well commented though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - How can the score be overshot?  The aim is to reduce the score to zero.  The score cannot be reduced to zero in fewer than nine darts.  It is impossible to overshoot.  I assumed most individuals would possess a rudimentary understanding of a dart board.  The numbers 1 to 20 may be hit with a dart; each number also has a double and a treble value.  The maximum score with a single dart is treble 20.  The lowest score is 0 (a miss) or 1 if hitting the board.

Comment: Does a treble count as one of the three required doubles?

Comment: overshoot means that for example, you have 40 pts left after 8 darts. Then the 9th dart shoots a treble 20 = 60 pts. Is that allowed / will lead to winning?

Comment: @TheMathTroll - that cannot happen.  It's impossible.  The minimum number of darts that can achieve 501 is 9.   If you go into a *negative* state you must continue from where you left off prior to going negative but you have exhausted that attempt.  The aim of the game is to reduce to zero but, if going into a negative state was the same as getting to zero...you could still only achieve it in 9 darts.  Therefore, overshoot or not it makes no discernible difference.

Comment: I know. but is it that if you go into a negative state, you are done also? or that turn is wasted?

Comment: In competitive play that turn is wasted.  However, for the sake of the question, even if we took a negative state as being the same as zero...it would still require a minimum of 9 darts.  The outcome is the same as the answer by Chas Brown.

Comment: Wait I might be wrong...forgive me.  If a negative state is equal to 0 (winning) and Chas has proven that all of the doubles must utilise the bullseye giving a guaranteed score of 150.  Therefore the question then becomes, with six darts, how many possible combinations can achieve 351 or higher?

Comment: @Venture: It would not be the same: we would have new winning combinations, such as throwing 6 triple-20s and 3 double-bullseyes.

Comment: That is why I wrote directly above your answer; "forgive me" and then articulated the new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that a treble does not count as one of the three doubles, let's look at the maximum score: which would be $510 = 6 \cdot 60 + 3 \cdot 50.$

Thus we must distribute "negative $9$" points among the 9 shots.

If any of the doubles is not a $50$ point double, it can at most be a $40$ point double; therefore all three double shots must be bull's eyes.

So the 'losses' must come from the trebles. $9$ is divisible by $3$ (fortunately!), so we have the 3 following options (in whatever shot order):

$3$ of $20$ trebles, $3$ of $19$ trebles, $3$ of bull's eye doubles.

$4$ of $20$ trebles, $1$ of $19$ treble, $1$ of $18$ treble, $3$ of bull's eye doubles.

$5$ of $20$ trebles, $1$ of $17$ trebles, $3$ of bull's eye doubles.

Comment: Perfect - thank you for the clear and concise answer.  Marked as the best answer (unless anyone can refute but I doubt it).  I am sure the mathematical fun with 501 is limitless; thank you for answering so well.

Comment: Your answer looks good to me, but I think there is a typo in your equation for the maximum score: shouldn't it read $510 = 6 \cdot \mathbb{60} + 3 \cdot 50$?

Comment: @Rob Athan - yes you're right; corrected!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hypothetical question because the standard game of darts is that a player has to reach exactly 501 points in a leg, with the last dart being a double, before his opponent.

If you REALLY want to have 3 doubles within a perfect 9 dart leg, you should be looking at T20, T19, Bull three times, which is the most likely way that a pro would go if he was to hit 3 doubles on the way to the perfect 9 darter.

Comment: Not hypothetical.  Already been answered.